# When having multiple simultanious SSH connections, only the first two can `sudo`

Tags: sudo, sshd

When there are multiple simultaneous SSH connections open, only the first two can `sudo`. In the third connection, one gets asked for a password, altough the user doesn't have a password set.

## First connection:

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~$ ssh manuel-nas-wan 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/manuel/.ssh/manuel-thinkpad-arbeit.ed25519': 
Linux manuel-nas 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Tue Dec  5 13:59:52 2017 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

user@manuel-nas:~$ sudo pwd
/home/user
```

## Second connection:

(Equal to first connection)

## Third connection:

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~$ ssh manuel-nas-wan
Enter passphrase for key '/home/manuel/.ssh/manuel-thinkpad-arbeit.ed25519': 
Linux manuel-nas 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Tue Dec  5 14:27:00 2017 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

user@manuel-nas:~$ sudo pwd
[sudo] password for user:
```

## Question

Can anyone tell me the reason, and how to deactivate this behavior? I want to be able to `sudo` from *all* of my connections, not just the first two.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the password you are asked for by `sudo` is your own, not root's. Root having or not having a password is irrelevant.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Of course, you're right. I corrected my post. Thank you!

Comment: You've to check the sudo rules with the `visudo` tool. By the way you've to check the sshd configuration in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file for acknowledge if ssh permit root login or not.

Comment: @dubis: Password-authentification is disabled for `root`, thanks for the reminder. `sudo visudo --check` emits: `/etc/sudoers: parsed OK\n /etc/sudoers.d/README: parsed OK`